# Rails + UUID generated schema assumes UUID is an integer rather than a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I’m trying to use a UUID as the primary key for a Rails app, and am running into problem after problem.

I am specifying in migration this:
    create_table :users, :id => false do |t|
then this:
    execute("ALTER TABLE users ADD PRIMARY KEY(uuid)")

In my user model:
  set_primary_key "uuid"

Using the UUID tools to generate the UUID.

This is all working great, the problem I currently have is that the schema.rb that gets generated looks like this:

create_table "users", :primary_key => "uuid", :force => true do |t|

Which assumes that the primary key column is an 11 character integer rather than a 36 character string, so running migrations produces a correct database, but test database is generated incorrectly, and if I were to run rake db:schema:load, it would fail as well...

Need to figure out how to override the way that schema.rb assumes that if there’s a primary key column that it will be an integer....

Answer (score 3):

I think the best approach is to switch from managing your schema in Ruby (schema.rb) to managing it in SQL (development_structure.sql).

To do this:

1. In application.rb set `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql`
2. Delete your schema.rb file.
3. Every time you run `rake db:migrate`, run `rake db:dump:structure` as well.  That will dump your schema to `db/development_structure.sql`.  When you run `rake db:test:prepare` it will now use the `development_structure.sql` file instead of the `scheam.rb` file.

You can read more about this in section 6.2 of the migrations guide (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html).

Comment: That's definitively the solution

Answer (score 1):

We have been using UUID as the primary key for a long time (currently with Rails 3.0.0), but so far have not found a way to make Schema dumper understand that there is no integer id.

So our solution has been fixing the schema by hand, when needed. For example always after `rake db:migrate`. :D

We just change the line

> create_table "people", :force => true do |t|

to

> create_table "people", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
>
> ```
> t.string   "id", :limit => 22,  :null => false
> ```

It's rather annoying but then everything works. So the problem is not in Rails not allowing UUID primary keys, but schema dumper not understanding those.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem. As far as i can tell, it's impossible to override rails' requirement that the PK be an integer. What i did to bypass this was add a key to unique on the database and then setup my default scopes on each model to search via my unique string instead of the regular integer